# css style for window list applet in gnome panel

Tags: gnome

I would like to edit my gtk3 theme css to change the appearance of the window list applet shown in the gnome panel. I have tried various selectors (WnckTasklist, WnckApplet, WindowListApplet, .window-list-item-box, .window-button) but none does anything. Does anyone know where the window list ui is coded or documented including all selectors that could refer to its widgets in css? I am running Ubuntu 13.04. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This should be moved to Super User, as this is config-related and not programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
WnckTasklist .button:hover  {}
WnckTasklist .button:active {}
```